# Move sign In or Create Account links to new container next to cart icon in header

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, layout

Does anyone know how to achieve below design.

1. Create a new container next to cart icon in header
2. move top bar sign in and create account links to new container.

Please kindly refer the screenshot attached

[image]

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

**step1:-** You should add the below code in
**app/design/frontend/[vendor-name]/[theme-name]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
 <move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart" />
```

**step2:-**You should add the below code in CSS File

```
ul.header.links {
    float: right;
}
```